# Find groupby columns from a pyspark.sql.GroupedData (Access df._jgd JavaObject?)

Tags: pyspark

Writing a function that needs to use the columns specified when a pyspark.sql.GroupedData is created.  The columns seem to be stored in the class's ._jgd attribute, which is a java object.  I have a hack/workaround (below) but would like to know if there's a way to access the contents of the java object directly.  Is there a 'good/best' way, what is recommended?

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data 
df = pd.DataFrame({'gcol1': ['a1','a1','a1','b2','b2','cc'],
                   'x1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'x2': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df = df.groupby('gcol1')
```

a list with ['gcol1'] is required.

My "hack" works, which is:

```
grouping_cols = df.count().columns
grouping_cols.reverse()
grouping_cols.remove('count')
grouping_cols.reverse()
print(grouping_cols)

['gcol1']
```

This hacky solution will usually be fine, but it would be better to access the information from the object.  The ._jgd attr seems to have the required information, but it is a JavaObject.

```
print(df._jgd)
RelationalGroupedDataset: [grouping expressions: [gcol1], value: [gcol1: string, x1: bigint ... 1 more field], type: GroupBy]
```

Comment: why the `reverse`?

Comment: Just in case the grouped dataframe already has a column called 'count'.  Hopefully this way will remove the one i'm adding.

Comment: What version of pyspark? I'm not seeing the same output for `print(df._jgd)`.

Comment: I think your "hack" is good, but you can simplify it to just `grouping_cols = df.count().columns[:-1]` since you know the `count` will be the last element of the list. Also you can use regular expressions on the string output of `print(df._jgd)`. The following pattern should work: `(?<=grouping expressions: \[).+?(?=], )`